# Show progress bar when Entity Framework transfer data

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, entity-framework

I have a project that uses data from  `Entity Framework` and present them in `WPF`. I want show threaded progress bar when Entity Framework load/save data on presentation layer.

Can you please help me to understand how can I do that?

Comment: EF does not provide a mechanism to notify the progress.

Comment: In general commits to EF should be fast enough that they dont need a progress bar, if you are finding that its taking a while your time would be better spent fixing the root cause than giving the user feedback on the progress of the commit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Dispatcher Thread to achieve this; Basically you need to create a common class that is extended in other UI classes.

To achieve this you can see [basic example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/265748/WPF-Progress-Bar-using-Threads) here; more precise example and downloadable code is available [here](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=571).

Answer (score 5):

I found this neat [example](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/linqtosql/thread/b62d7502-1fcd-4cbd-92f9-3f10e4ed215f) to do that using `Skip`/`Take` methods. Basically you load x amount of records each round, which you `Skip` on the next round, and calculate this from the amount of all data in your table which enables you to update the progress bar each round.

Take a look at this:

```
List<MyDataTable> someData = new List<MyDataTable>();
int rowCount = dt.myDataTable.Count();

//TODO: <= display a progress bar here, and set max to rowCount...

int currentRows = 0;
while (currentRows < rowCount)
{
  someData.AddRange(dt.myDataTable.Skip(currentRows).Take(10000).ToList());
  currentRows = someData.Count;

  //TODO: <= update progress here...

}
```

Comment: It's the only option it seems, but for the record, skip is inefficient (sql dbs can't seek on rowcounts). Entity Framework really should have support for this. Large exports need this.